# Managing php config with ansible - lineinfile php.ini vs copy to php.d?

Tags: php, linux, ansible

I'm learning ansible and looking to automate php configuration.

When I look at examples, nearly all are using lineinfile to change /etc/php.ini

This approach works, but seems a bit brittle to me.

Wouldn't it be better to add a custom /etc/phpd./90-site.ini file with all the options you want to customize in one whole shot using copy or template? This depends on PHP being compiled with the --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d option but that seems to be the case mostly nowadays. And the actual ansible code will be dead easy, with all the configuration in a template file.

What am I missing?

What are the pros and cons of overriding a configuration file using a multiple lineinfile tasks versus a single copy task?

Comment: What actually prevents you to at least try to implement things the way you think it is best? From my point of view, lineinfile is adapted if you have very few changes to make from a default configuration. If you have more than that, copy/template is much more convenient. In this later case, the fact that you replace an entire default config file or add to a config dir does not have much importance (or at least deploying via ansible is not the driver for this choice).

Comment: > What actually prevents you to at least try to implement things the way you think it is best?

It's more a question of ansible best practices since I'm not familiar with it so I don't really know what's "best".

Comment: Implement your replacements/additions with lineinfile. Evaluate the difficulty to maintain that (adding more params, Integrate defaults from upstream). Time the task(s) to see how long it will take everytime you run your playbook. Now do the same exercise with copy/template. If I had more than 10 parameters to manage, I'll probably prefer the second option. But that's opinion based therefore off-topic. Using php.ini or php.d has nothing to do with ansible good practice nor programming with php. It is more an OS management issue and is dangerously on the edge of being off-topic on SO too.

Comment: > Using php.ini or php.d has nothing to do with ansible good practice nor programming with php. It is more an OS management issue and is dangerously on the edge of being off-topic on SO too.

I suppose you are aware that ansible is a tool for system configuration aka "OS management"? 

Comment: And I suppose you are aware we discuss here mainly problems about writing ansible scripts, using filters, defining datastructures, looping over them, developing custom plugins and inventories, architecturing roles and collections.... whereas pure problems about installing ansible itself, using a specific tool on a specific OS to install a particular package, to connect to machines in your Infra..... should be discussed in https://superuser.com or https://servefault.com. As you are also probably aware that pure questions about installing php should go there as well.

Comment: No worries, I got help on a subreddit in like 10 minutes hahah

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into an opinion based answer, let me point you to a hint on the lineinfile module's [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html):

> This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.

Considering this, if you have multiple lines of configuration to change, using template module to manage a file like - `/etc/php.d/90-site.ini` makes sense.

Comment: So I has 7 lines to override, which looked like a lot of tasks to maintain, in addition to the issue of possible changes in the source file and regex to maintain. I ended up using a single copy command task and a single file. Works perfectly. Easy.